# strange behaviour while importing modules

Tags: python, python-import

I have Python package called just "package". In it I have empty `__init__.py` and two modules. One is called `m1.py` and contains just one line:

```
x = 3
```

The other one is called `m2.py` and contains this line:

```
x = 5
```

Now I try to use that modules. First I do something like that:

```
from package.m1 import x
print package.m1.x
```

Of course it does not work - I get such error:

```
NameError: name 'package' is not defined
```

And I understand why it does not work. But then I do something like that:

```
from package.m1 import x
import package.m2
print package.m1.x
```

And now it does work. Why? How? I did not import package.m1!

Answer (score 2):

I have only one explanation for this:

1. `from package.m1 import x` loads the modules `package` and `package.m1`. `m1` is added to the `package` module but `package` is not added to your globals.
2. `import package.m2` now adds the `package` module to your globals. Since `m1` is already part of `package` it is now accessible via `package.m1`.

Further testing:

```
>>> from package import m1
>>> package.m1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'package' is not defined
>>> import package.m2
>>> package.m1
<module 'package.m1' from 'package/m1.py'>
>>> from package import m3
>>> package.m3
<module 'package.m3' from 'package/m3.py'>
```

Testing continued:

```
>>> import package.m1
>>> del package
>>> import package
>>> package.m1
<module 'package.m1' from 'package/m1.py'>
```

Comment: That is indeed the case. The check is simple: `import sys; print sys.modules['package']` after the first `import` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The `from x import y` syntax import the whole module and then reference the specified object in the current namespace. It can be translated as:

```
import x
y = x.y
```

So, you're actually importing package.m1

Comment: Completely wrong, importing a package doesn't automatically import all the modules.